# Experience with Open AI`s Assistant API and saved messages in Database

Tags: php, mysql, chatgpt-api

It is possible to migrate from database driven chat/completion behavior to assistants api methods. I will not lost my data from conversation und also I will use the optimization functions from assistants api.

I use open AI php client in Laravel for the beta assistants api. Currently I have this solution:

```
    $messages = Message::where(user_id, Auth::id())->orderBy('created_at', 'asc') -> select(['role', 'content']);
    $chatMessages = $messages->map(function ($item) {
            return ['role' => $item->role, 'content' => $item->content];
        });
    $chat_instruction = 'this is a super bot';
    $message_instruction = ['role' => 'assistant', 'content' => $chat_instruction];
        $chatMessages->prepend($message_instruction);
    $response = $client->chat()->create([
            'model' => 'gpt-4-1106-preview',
            'messages' => $chatMessages,
            'temperature' => 0,
            'tools' => $tools,
        ]);
```

EDIT:

okay i implemented more than less without database connection:

```
    public function postMessage($user, $content, $role)
{
    $this->getOrCreateThreat();
    $now = Carbon::now();
    //create user content
    $response = $this->openAIClient->threads()->messages()->create($this->threadId, [
        'role' => $role,
        'content' => "$now:::\n\n {$content}",
        'metadata' => ['request_date' => $now]
    ]);
    foreach ($response->content as $content) {
        $message = new Message;
        $message->role = $response->role;
        $message->content = $content->text->value;
        $user->messages()->save($message);
    }

    //run thread
    $response = $this->openAIClient->threads()->runs()->create(
        threadId: $this->threadId,
        parameters: [
            'assistant_id' => $this->assistantId,
            'metadata' => ['request_date' => $now],
            'instructions' => config('chat.instruction').'\n\n Please add the current Timestamp to every Message.'
        ]
    );
    while (true) {
        sleep(0.2);
         $responseRetrieve = $this->openAIClient->threads()->runs()->retrieve(
             threadId: $this->threadId,
             runId: $response->id,
         );

        if ($responseRetrieve->status == 'completed') {
            break;
        } elseif ($responseRetrieve->status == 'failed' ) {
            throw new Exception('assistant run fails');
        } elseif ($responseRetrieve->status == 'expired' ) {
            throw new Exception('assistant run is expired');
        }
        elseif ($responseRetrieve->status == 'requires_action' ) {
            $this->callRequiredFunctions($responseRetrieve->id, $responseRetrieve->requiredAction);
        }
    }

    $response = $this->openAIClient->threads()->messages()->list($this->threadId);
    //throw new Exception(json_encode($response->data));

    $answer =  collect($response->data)->firstOrFail(function ($object) {
        return $object->role == 'assistant';
    });
    //throw new Exception(json_encode($answer));

    $collection = collect();

    foreach ($answer['content'] as $message) {
        //throw new Exception(json_encode($message));
        $collection->add(['role' => $answer['role'], 'content' => $message['text']['value']]);
        //$collection->add($message->text->value);
    }
    //throw new Exception(json_encode($collection));
    return $collection->toArray();
}
```